# Find and replace text on multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sed

I am trying to replace a specific link which exists on many html pages with its https version.  I have tried:

```
grep -rl "http://server.iad.liveperson.net/hc/88956865/" ./ | xargs sed -i "s/http:\/\/server.iad.liveperson.net\/hc\/88956865\//https:\/\/server.iad.liveperson.net\/hc\/88956865\//g"
```

When I do this, even as `sudo`, I am getting

```
sed: couldn't open temporary file ./customers/sedTR3AMu: Permission denied
```

`customers` is just the first directory in `./`. So, it is hanging on the first file I reckon, but not sure what is wrong beyond that.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use a different delimiter with `sed`. `sed 's_http://server.iad.liveperson.net/hc/88956865/_https://server.iad.liveperson.net/hc/88956865/_g` because `sed` is confused where the delimiter starts and ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to run the command logged in as root because sed -i creates temporary files in /tmp and needed write access.

Thanks:Used jim's syntax with the semicolons which worked fine.  ooga, I did not have to escape the literal periods.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you should try is to run the `sed` command as stand alone, for a file that you previously know that contains that string.  I have the feeling that the `sed` command might be complaining about the `/` characters...

You should try changing the `sed` command to something like:

```
sed -i 's;http://server.iad.liveperson.net/hc/88956865/;https://server.iad.liveperson.net/hc/88956865/;g'
```

That is, using `;` instead of `/` as the delimiter, so you don't have to escape the `/` every time using `\`.

Comment: The literal periods should have backslashes before them.